# Pythonically add source attribution link to application display

Tags: python, open-source, pyqt4, openstreetmap, qgis

I'm building an application out of QGIS 2.8 with PyQt4, and I'm referencing OpenStreetMap tiles as a basemap. I'd like to credit OpenStreetMap with a small source attribution and a link at the bottom right of my application window, but I don't know how to do it. No amount of research I've done has provided any steps to do this in Python. The best I've found is that this is doable in HTML, which makes sense, as usually webmaps are added to websites. This is a standalone application built out of Python, however, so I'm not sure where to begin.

All I'd like to add is something like this:

[image]